# join/merge two columns inside a data-frame

Tags: r, join, merge, data-management

Say I have this data,

```
(df <- data.frame( col1 = c('My','Your','His','Thir'), col2 = c('Cat','Dog','Fish','Dog')))

  col1 col2
1   My  Cat
2 Your  Dog
3  His Fish
4 Thir  Dog
```

and I want to combine the columns like this

```
`some magic`

  col1 col2      col3
1   My  Cat    My Cat
2 Your  Dog  Your Dog
3  His Fish  His Fish
4 Thir  Dog  Thir Dog
```

What do I do? maybe even with a comma (,) like this,

```
`some magic`

  col1 col2      col3
1   My  Cat    My, Cat
2 Your  Dog  Your, Dog
3  His Fish  His, Fish
4 Thir  Dog  Thir, Dog
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`df$col3 <- paste(df$col1, df$col2, sep=",")`. You can also use the `sprintf` and `paste0` functions.

```
df$col3 <- paste(df$col1, df$col2, sep=",") # comma separator
df$col3 <- paste0(df$col1, df$col2) # for no separator
```

Comment: what if we are dealing with empty values as well? how do we handle extra commas

Comment: I am still waiting for your response. suppose the data is that `col1` is blank and `col2` has cat. wouldn't the resultant value be `, cat`. how to deal with that? I just need `cat`. the resultant could even be `, , cat, , , dog` if we are playing with multiple columns

Comment: @Saksham The `ifelse` function should be what you're looking for. You might need several nested calls `ifelse(..., ..., ifelse(...))` for multiple columns. For just one column that might be blank it would look like `ifelse(df$col1 == "", df$col2, paste(df$col1, df$col2, sep=","))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leave them as a list of the two, (not a string concatenating both) then the following will work well

```
within(df, col3 <- Map(list, as.character(col1),as.character(col2)))  

  col1 col2      col3
1   My  Cat   My, Cat
2 Your  Dog Your, Dog
3  His Fish His, Fish
4 Thir  Dog Thir, Dog
```

`Map` is a simple wrapper for `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I'll play around with it later.

Comment: what if we are dealing with empty values as well? how do we handle extra commas

Comment: I am still waiting for your response. suppose the data is that `col1` is blank and `col2` has cat. wouldn't the resultant value be `, cat`. how to deal with that? I just need `cat`. the resultant could even be `, , cat, , , dog` if we are playing with multiple columns